# How to publish patch versions on previous minor/major version in lerna using github workflows

Tags: github, github-actions, lerna

I am handling few packages with Lerna and yarn. I have a GitHub workflow set up to publish the new version for the changed packages when pushed to main using conventional commits.

let's say I have

```
package-a: 1.4.0

package-b:  3.3.11
```

As we progress, we published a major version for `package-a: 2.0.0`.

Now if we want to create a patch release for package-a i.e. 1.4.1, how can I achieve this with Lerna and a proper GitHub workflow that will not disturb my original workflow.

Comment: Does it have to be with Lerna? `git cherry-pick` could also do it using tags with the commit you want to include in the patch.

Comment: Preferable to do it with Lerna as it maintains the tags. Also by doing cherry-pick, how would I automate the publishing part in regular CI/CD?

Comment: You can use cherry-pick to add the patch PR commit to the previous tag, then create a new tag from this branch. Once you're here, you can have another workflow (or job) that would trigger when a tag is generated to publish the new package automatically according to your context.

Comment: Nice ... is there a way where Lerna can help up? I guess the above manual method requires the user to determine the version number.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lerna, but as github actions is very customizable, it may be possible to use it, or a script, to generate and manage your tags according to your context.